# Is there a name for (close-open)/(high-low)?

Tags: equities

(close-open)/(high-low) may contain useful information about stock prices. Is there a commonly accepted name for this quantity?

Comment: Think this is known as Interbar Rank (IBR) or Internal Bar Strength(IBS).

Comment: It is not. IBS is(close-low)/(high-low). I am asking (close-open)/(high-low).

Answer (score 2):

If it weren't on Google, it wouldn't exist. Fortunately it is. It is called `Balance of Power (BoP)`

[image]

The second link explains it is a simplification of Igor Livshin's balance of market power (BMP) indicator. If you google BOP, you will find links like
[Balance of Power (BOP)](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000589100-balance-of-power-bop/)

Comment: @user15502206, if this answered your question please consider also accepting it.